# Calculating Datediff of two days based on when the sum of a column hits a number cap

Tags: sql, sum, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, datediff

Tried to see if this was asked anywhere else but doesn't seem like it. Trying to create a sql query to give me the date difference in days between '2022-10-01' and the date when our impression sum hits our cap of 5.

For context, we may see duplicate dates because someone revisit our website that day so we'll get a different session number to pair with that count. Here's an example table of one individual and how many impressions logged.

My goal is to get the number of days it takes to hit an impression cap of 5. So for this individual, they would hit the cap on '2022-10-07' and the days between '2022-10-01' and '2022-10-07' is 6. I am also calculating the difference before/after '2023-01-01' since I need this count for Q4 of '22 and Q1 of '23 but will not include in the example table. I have other individuals to include but for the purpose of asking here, I kept it to one.

Current Query:

```
    select 
    click_date, 
    case 
      when date(click_date) < date('2023-01-01') and sum(impression_cnt = 5) then datediff('day', '2022-10-01', click_date)
      when date(click_date) >= date('2023-01-01') and sum(impression_cnt = 5) then datediff('day', '2023-01-01', click_date)
    else 0 
    end days_to_capped
    from table
    group by customer, click_date, impression_cnt
```

| customer | click date | impression_cnt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 2022-10-05 | 2 |
| 123456 | 2022-10-05 | 1 |
| 123456 | 2022-10-06 | 1 |
| 123456 | 2022-10-07 | 1 |
| 123456 | 2022-10-11 | 1 |
| 123456 | 2022-10-11 | 3 |

Result Table

| customer | days_to_cap |
| --- | --- |
| 123456 | 6 |

I'm currently only getting 0 days and then 81 days once it hits 2022-12-21 (last date) for this individual so i know I need to fix my query. Any help would be appreciated!

Edited: This is in snowflake!

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (DATEDIFF is a product specific function.)

Comment: I'm in snowflake if that answers your question!

Answer (score 0):

So, the issue with your query is that the sum is being calculated at the level that you are grouping by, which is every field, so it will always just be the value of the impressions field every time.

What you need to do is a running sum, which is a `SUM() OVER (PARTITION BY...)` statement.  And then qualify the results of that:

First, just to get the data that you have:

```
with x as (
select *
from values
(123456,'2022-10-05'::date,2),
(123456,'2022-10-05'::date,1),
(123456,'2022-10-06'::date,1),
(123456,'2022-10-07'::date,1),
(123456,'2022-10-11'::date,1),
(123456,'2022-10-11'::date,3) x (customer,click_date,impression_cnt)
)
```

Then, I query the CTE to do the running sum with a `QUALIFY` statement to choose the record that actually has the value I'm looking for

```
select
customer,
case 
  when click_date < '2023-01-01'::date and sum(impression_cnt) OVER (partition by customer order by click_date) = 5 then datediff('day', '2022-10-01', click_date)
  when click_date >= '2023-01-01'::date and sum(impression_cnt) OVER (partition by customer order by click_date) = 5 then datediff('day', '2023-01-01', click_date)
else 0 
end days_to_capped
from x
qualify days_to_capped > 0;
```

The qualify filters your results to just the record that you cared about.

Comment: Another benefit of using `QUALIFY`, btw, is that you could also output the `click_date` and the `impression_cnt` and even the running sum of impression cnt for the qualifying record without having to do a join back or sub-query.  This is a very clean query in Snowflake, and I'm a big fan of the `QUALIFY` option.